# Slow rendering performance for 500 rows and 12 columns table

Tags: performance, jsf, render

I am using Mojarra 2.1.19. I have a simple Facelet which contains only one table with 500 rows and 12 columns. The cells contain only text property data. It needs about 2 seconds to execute the render response phase.

As a result the application is not very responsive. Also all rows must be seen. The client doesn't want pagination.

Any suggestions? Is Mojarra really so slow?

Comment: Performance also depends on client used. Particularly IE has trouble with "overzealously big" tables. Have you profiled it? Better do it before making assumptions. Also try latest Mojarra version. It's 2.1.29 already for 2.1.x.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) I am using latest Chrome. Also tried to switch to `2.1.29` but the performance is the same. I am profiling the render response phase using this: http://www.byteality.ch/blog/?p=17.

Comment: JSF is obligatory for all your proyect?  I think in others solutions: JSON+JQuery, XML+JAXB or a new tag in JSP.

Comment: Yes, `JSF` is obligatory.

Comment: That wasn't an answer :) That article doesn't describe profiling ...

Comment: I mean it displays how much the render response phase took. What can I do more? Could you give me suggestions?

Comment: If possible create a new component in JSF for this case?

Comment: I changed `<h:outputText value="#{person.firstName}"/>` to `#{person.firstName}` for all columns, and it became a lot faster - exceutin time `200 ms`. So JSF's problem is the number of components? Because `outputText` is a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, there was `JSF` debug logging turned on, and it made the execution slower. I turned off the logging and the simple table is fast now.